# Cannot get my program to print "Usage: ./caesar"

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently doing cs50 course, I am doing the caesar cipher problem and have come across a problem.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    // argument count, array of strings
    int main (int argc, string argv[])

{
    //checking there is only one command line argument, checking if digit
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
{    //atoi converts string to int
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    //get plaintext
    string s = get_string ("Plain text: ");
    printf("ciphertext: \n");

   if (argc !=2)
       printf("Usage: ./ceasar\n");
   }    
}
```

I cannot get my program to print "Usage: ./caesar"

If I enter ./cipher 2 it returns

Plaintext:

but if I enter say `./caesar g` it returns to a blank line in terminal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a good example why you should indent your code properly. It would jump right in your eye with proper indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You miss an `else` branch:

```
if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
{   //atoi converts string to int
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    //get plaintext
    string s = get_string ("Plain text: ");
    printf("ciphertext: \n");
    ... // the rest of your code
}
else
{
    printf("Usage: ./ceasar\n"); // You mean Usage: ./ceasar param
}
```

Comment: thanks david, i also realise i dont need (argc !=2) i can do away with that just by using an else like u suggested,

i felt it was something i was overlooking, i just couldnt get my head around it,

thanks for taking the time to help me, im at the start of my learning

Answer (score 0):

It's a better practice to check arguments first and exit earlier.  Here is a [link](https://cee.studio/200527-4UG/rjEBw) to run the code. You might need it later when you encounter segfaults.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// argument count, array of strings
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
      printf("Usage: ./ceasar\n");
      exit (1);
  }

  // checking there is only one command line argument, checking if digit
  if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1])) { // atoi converts string to int
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    // get plaintext
    string s = get_string("Plain text: ");
    printf("ciphertext: \n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, ill book mark the site to check code on for sure, i like the idea of checking arguements first so no need to go through whole program, i will remmebre this.
thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition has no else branch,

```
if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
```

checks if the input is a digit, if `g` is entered, the condition fails and the code in the `if` block is not executed, and the program exits with exit code 0. Use:

```
if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
{
//Your code
}
else
{
//Else code if your condition fails
}
```